# Regex to extract curl options

Tags: regex, bash, curl

I have curl command as string and I want to extract options with a regex. I don't know how to select `-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch'` for example.

Could you help me ?

```
curl 'http://en.wikipedia.org/' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Referer: http://www.wikipedia.org/'  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --compressed
```

I think get `--compressed` is easier to catch and `--[a-zA-Z]+` is enough.

Comment: To answer this generally, you'd have to know for each option if it takes an argument or not, if the arguments can ever be quoted with double quotes etc., which would make this very complex. Can you make the question more specific, for example, about just headers? Or any other precise definition of what it is you want? And in which output format?

Comment: All options which start by - following or not by an argument. And following curl syntax I think I can have simple quote, double quote or none. My goal is to parse any curl command to convert them in another language like PHP, java, js ...

Comment: That's extremely broad then.

Answer (score 0):

For the example you provided, I think this does what you are looking for.

It is only looking for groups that start with `-H` and have `''` around the values.

```regex
(-H '[^']*')
```

see: https://regex101.com/r/YAna2M/1